# js flot 0.8.3 pie chart not resizing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, flot

I am using js flot version 0.8.3 with bootstrap 3. The resize plugin is working fine with bar chart, but not with pie chart. Would appreciate help.

I have just included the jquery, flot and resize plugins, and drew my chart like this:

```
var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, options);
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the pie chart:

https://jsfiddle.net/w999qvo9/

Answer (score 0):

Your container div for the pie chart has fixed width and height, so it never gets resized, use relative dimensions (e.g. [viewport units](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values-3/#viewport-relative-lengths)) and it works ([see updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w999qvo9/2/)):

```
#placeholder{
    width: 95vw;
    height: 95vh;
}
```

Comment: thanks, didn't know of viewport units. It's still not working within bootstrap's responsive layout though. even though I have fixed width and height, it's working by bar chart. any idea?

Comment: Can you extend your fiddle with the bootstrap responsive layout?